# single stat with plotly and python

Tags: python, plotly

Im trying to plot a single stat in plotly, so only one number (with a text). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Example: Single Stat Plot

[image: Single Stat Plot]

Comment: Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @user32185 if i could do that i would not have to ask the question right? 
Basically what i need is:
`trace_1 = go.? (x = str(name), y = singleValue)`
so instead of x and y positions i only need a centered output containing a single value and ideally a text

Comment: Not really. You could post a piece of code you are plotting. Just to understand if you are using a variable, a dataframe or other things.

Comment: i use the standard subplot approach "Multiple Custom Sized Subplots" https://plot.ly/python/subplots/